# Why my MQL5 indicator is displaying one moving average instead of two?

Tags: buffer, algorithmic-trading, moving-average, mql5, forex

I took the code of VIDYA from the examples library of MQL5 and added a second moving average to it; basically, another VIDYA line.

The newly created code is **compiling without errors or warnings** but only one moving average (VIDYA) is being displayed on the chart **instead of two**. It seems I am missing something. Your help will be much appreciated!

```
#property copyright   "2009-2020, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link        "http://www.mql5.com"
#property description "Double Variable Index Dynamic Average"

//--- indicator settings

#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers    2
#property indicator_plots      2

#property indicator_type1      DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color1     Navy
#property indicator_width1     3
#property indicator_label1     "VIDYA 1"

#property indicator_type2      DRAW_LINE
#property indicator_color2     Navy
#property indicator_width2     3
#property indicator_label2     "VIDYA 2"

#property indicator_applied_price  PRICE_MEDIAN

//--- input parameters
input int InpPeriodCMO = 9;   // Period CMO
input int InpPeriodEMA = 12;  // Period EMA
input int InpShift     = 0;   // Indicator's shift

//--- indicator buffer
double VIDYA_Buffer_1[];
double VIDYA_Buffer_2[];

double ExtF; // smooth factor
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnInit()
{
//--- indicator buffers mapping
  SetIndexBuffer(0, VIDYA_Buffer_1, INDICATOR_DATA);
  SetIndexBuffer(1, VIDYA_Buffer_2, INDICATOR_DATA);

//--- sets first bar from what index will be drawn
  PlotIndexSetInteger(0, PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN, InpPeriodEMA+InpPeriodCMO-1);
  PlotIndexSetInteger(1, PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN, InpPeriodEMA+InpPeriodCMO-1);

//--- sets indicator shift
  PlotIndexSetInteger(0, PLOT_SHIFT, InpShift);
  PlotIndexSetInteger(1, PLOT_SHIFT, InpShift);

//--- name for indicator label
  string short_name = StringFormat("VIDYA(%d,%d)", InpPeriodCMO, InpPeriodEMA);

  IndicatorSetString(INDICATOR_SHORTNAME,short_name);
  PlotIndexSetString(0, PLOT_LABEL, short_name+"1");
  PlotIndexSetString(1, PLOT_LABEL, short_name+"2");

//--- calculate smooth factor
  ExtF = 2.0/(1.0+InpPeriodEMA);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Variable Index Dynamic Average                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
        const int prev_calculated,
        const int begin,
        const double &price[])
{
  if(rates_total < InpPeriodEMA+InpPeriodCMO-1)
    return(0);
//---
  int i,start;
  if(prev_calculated < InpPeriodEMA+InpPeriodCMO-1)
  {
    start = InpPeriodEMA+InpPeriodCMO-1;
    for(i = 0; i<start; i++)
    {
      VIDYA_Buffer_1[i] = price[i];
      VIDYA_Buffer_2[i] = price[i];
    }
  }
  else
    start = prev_calculated-1;
//--- main cycle
  for(i = start; i<rates_total && !IsStopped(); i++)
  {
    double mul_CMO = MathAbs(CalculateCMO(i,InpPeriodCMO,price));
    //--- calculate VIDYA 1 & 2
    VIDYA_Buffer_1[i] = price[i]*ExtF*mul_CMO+VIDYA_Buffer_1[i-1]*(1-ExtF*mul_CMO)*1;
    VIDYA_Buffer_2[i] = price[i]*ExtF*mul_CMO+VIDYA_Buffer_2[i-1]*(1-ExtF*mul_CMO)*2;
  }
//--- OnCalculate done. Return new prev_calculated.
  return(rates_total);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Chande Momentum Oscillator                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double CalculateCMO(int pos,const int period,const double &price[])
{
  double res = 0.0;
  double sum_up = 0.0,sum_down = 0.0;
//---
  if(pos >= period && pos<ArraySize(price))
  {
    for(int i = 0; i<period; i++)
    {
      double diff = price[pos-i]-price[pos-i-1];
      if(diff>0.0)
        sum_up += diff;
      else
        sum_down += (-diff);
    }
    if(sum_up+sum_down != 0.0)
      res = (sum_up-sum_down)/(sum_up+sum_down);
  }
//---
  return(res);
}
```

Comment: You calculations are resulting in the second buffer being out of range. Change the calc to `VIDYA_Buffer_2[i] = price[i]*ExtF*mul_CMO+VIDYA_Buffer_2[i-1]*(1-ExtF*mul_CMO)*2;` and you will be able to see it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want actually to modify the final value that is calculated but no matter what I add to the equation, it is simply vanishing from the chart. How to ensure that the buffer is always in range?

Comment: There is no "one way" and it entirely depends on your calculations. You need to ensure that the result is a value that will be visible on the chart (ie within the price range that is being displayed)